# Find the region f is holomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis

The function is $f(z) = \frac{\sin{z}}{z^3 + 1}$. My tactic was

1. Express f(z) in cartesian form.
2. Find $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$. $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$.
3. Compute the set $\{x + iy : (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}) \land (\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x})\}$

However, this quickly became algebraically unwieldly. Is my way even correct? Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: This is a quotient of holomorphic functions, and the denominator is non-zero provided that $z$ is not a cube root of $-1$. So $f$ is holomorphic except for three points.